# Can't add variable to an instance of List

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I'd like to add a variable called `foo` to the weights of a Conv2D layer to keep track of some book keeping.

This is my attempt:

```
kernels = model.get_layer(name='conv2d_1').get_weights()
kernels.foobar = 4
```

Note that `kernels` is of type `list`.
However, the previous code produce the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foobar'
```

Any idea?

Comment: For bookkeeping purposes, why not just use the layer name? The weights are associated with the layer, as is the name, and you can find layers by name (your code does just that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `kernels.__setattr__('foobar', 4)` / `setattr(kernels, 'foobar', 4)` in the way that you want, so you can't set an arbitrary attribute like you can with a custom class.

Perhaps in this case you do a very basic subclass on `list`:

```
class Kernels(list):
    def __setattr__(self, attr, x):
        # Make sure you aren't overriding some method of lists,
        # such as `.append()`
        if attr in self.__dir__():
            raise ValueError('%s is already a method.')
        super().__setattr__(attr, x)

>>> k = Kernels([1, 2, 3])
>>> k.foobar = 4  
>>> k
[1, 2, 3]
>>> k.foobar
4
```

Comment: Because list is a 'native' C class?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure, but that's probably relevant.  You can't call `setattr()` for any builtin types as far as I know.